# how to search for a null/empty value in a array,then erase and update the field with other values

Tags: delphi, dymo

I am printing a labels using delphi.  I am storing values in an array and printing the same. I would like to know, how we can remove the space when i do not have a value for a label and bring the next label to utilize the space provided for null or empty value.

Comment: It sounds like a job for the Good Ole' `if` statement, but please post some code, so we can give a more solid advice.

Comment: Use `TArray.Where<T>` from https://github.com/SirRufo/stateless/blob/master/Stateless/Stateless.Utils.pas#L379

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi 7 use good old dynamic arrays.

Using value type of string, you can solve the problem as follows:

Make a new VCL application, place a memo and then:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure DynamicStringArrayWay;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.DynamicStringArrayWay;
var
  ValueArray : array of string;
  n : Integer;
  n2 : Integer;
begin
  SetLength(ValueArray, 6);

  // fill array:
  ValueArray[0] := 'LabelA';
  ValueArray[1] := '';
  ValueArray[2] := 'LabelB';
  ValueArray[3] := '';
  ValueArray[4] := 'LabelC';
  ValueArray[5] := 'LabelD';

  // reduce:
  for n := Length(ValueArray)-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if (ValueArray[n]='') then
    begin
      // delete element n:
      for n2 := n to Length(ValueArray)-2 do
         ValueArray[n2] := ValueArray[n2+1];
      SetLength(ValueArray, Length(ValueArray)-1);
    end;
  end;

  // print:
  for n := 0 to Length(ValueArray)-1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add( ValueArray[n] );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DynamicStringArrayWay;
end;


end.
```

Comment: TValue might be a "bad" name since there is allready a Datatype in Delphi called TValue. You should think more generic, since you hardcoded it to a string array.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt: The TValue is for the sake of example. Due to the limited knowledge of what item type is required, it was my choice to make this part easy to modify. In the example I then used string type for easy illustration.

Comment: I am using delphi 7 and i use Array of String to store values

Comment: Doesn't the used reducing algorithm lack some performance? For worst case it would be O(n^2), wouldn't it? Is there `TStringList` available in Delphi 7?

Comment: @RenéHoffmann so if performance is important, and the number of elements is huge it will be worth considering. Otherwise I would not spend time on it.

Answer (score -1):

So if I understand you right you have an `Array` with **string** values  like this `['Item1', 'Item2', '', 'Item4']` and you want to remove the empty item so it becomes `['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item4']`?

As stated in the comment this could be done with a good old **if** statement but I rather give you a generic solution.

First thing is to create a new unit with a helper that can remove any given value from your array.

```
unit ArrayHelperU;

interface

type
  ArrayHelper = record
    class procedure RemoveAll<T>(var Values: TArray<T>; const Value: T); static;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Generics.Defaults;

{ TArrayHelper }

class procedure ArrayHelper.RemoveAll<T>(var Values: TArray<T>; const Value: T);
var
  I, Count: Integer;
  EqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<T>;
begin
  EqualityComparer := TEqualityComparer<T>.Default;

  Count := 0;

  for I := low(Values) to high(Values) do
    if not EqualityComparer.Equals(Values[I], Value) then
    begin
      Values[Count] := Values[I];
      inc(Count);
    end;

  SetLength(Values, Count);
end;

end.
```

Next step is to call it. In my little demo project I've put a `TMemo` on blank form and then I call the helper from `FormCreate`

```
uses
  ArrayHelperU;

procedure TForm36.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Values: TArray<string>;
  Buffer, Element: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  //Make room for 10 elements
  Setlength(Values, 10);

  //Initialize the aray with some dummy values
  //Some of them are blanks
  for i := Low(Values) to High(Values) do
    if i mod 2 = 0 then
      Values[i] := 'Item' + IntToStr(i);


  //Print the array to the screen
  Memo1.Lines.Text := 'BEFORE: ';
  Buffer := '[';
  for Element in Values do
    Buffer := Buffer + #39 + Element + #39 + ' ,';
  Buffer[Length(Buffer)] := ']';
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Buffer);

  //Call our ArrayHelper from befor
  ArrayHelper.RemoveAll<string>(Values, '');

  //Print the array to the screen
  Buffer := '[';
  for Element in Values do
    Buffer := Buffer + #39 + Element + #39 + ' ,';
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('AFTER:');
  Buffer[Length(Buffer)] := ']';
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Buffer);
end;
```

I've placed comments in the code so you can see how it works.

Only thing left is to show the result.

[image]